# How to convert mac pem ssh keys to windows putty style on shell?

Tags: ssh, putty, ssh-keys

How can mac ssh keys (id_dsa pem file) be converted to windows putty style (ppk) on shell?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure if there are any utilities allowing for pem -> ppk conversion on the terminal.
You may just have to use Puttys' [PuTTYgen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) in order to convert.